# Router link active when child component is active

Tags: angular

```
{ 
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent, 
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: DashboardHomeComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
        },
        {
            path: 'em',
            component: EmComponent,
        }
        {
            path: 'ec',
            component: EcComponent,
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the li-bg class to stay in dashbord menu link if the user goes to em or ec components.
I cant remove [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" because then it will be active for all the links starting with /dashboard
Is there a way to do it.

Dashboard Home HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <a routerLink="/dashboard/em">Em Service</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <a routerLink="/dashboard/ec">Ec Service</a>
    </div>
</row>
```

DashboardComponent

```
 <div class="Sidebar">
    <a routerLinkActive="li-bg" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" routerLink="/">Dashboard</a>
    <a routerLink="/dashboard/my-profile">My profile</a>
  </div>
```

Links

```
dashboard/ is home
dashboard/em is em component
dashboard/ec is e component
```

Comment: you can use `routerLinkActive="router-link-active"` to active the current active link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive and the [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) class to add/remove one or several css-classes with a parant's html-tag. In this example, a css-class is added when a certain component-method (`handleActiveClass`) return `true` and vise versa. In this way you can control when a parent's class should be added or removed depending on what child-page an user is right now.

DashboardComponent-TS:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

class DashboardComponent{

   constructor(private location: Location) {

   }

   handleActiveClass(){
     let relativePath: string = this.location.path();
     return relativePath === '/dashboard/em' || relativePath === '/dashboard/ec';
   }

}
```

DashboardComponent-HTML:

```
<a [ngClass]="{'li-bg':handleActiveClass()}"
   routerLink="/">Dashboard</a>
```